# system command accessing folders with spaces

Tags: matlab

I'm currently trying to write a program that requires I access files on a OneDrive folder that will be shared with multiple computers. Currently, an issue is appearing where the 'system' command is throwing an error when I try and access the OneDrive folder because the full path name has spaces in it.

```
folder = '/Users/myuser/Desktop/OneDrive\ -\ -\ Company\ Name/foldername-AVL'
STR = sprintf('cd %s',folder);
system(STR)
```

The error I keep receiving is

> /bin/bash: line 0: cd: %s/Users/myuser/Desktop/OneDrive: No such file
>   or directory

So it is effectively cutting off all entries after the second space. I've looked through the documentation and all, and I can't seem to find a solution or a guide for using the system command in this specific situation.

Comment: Did you examine the contents of `STR` to see what it looks like? I believe `sprintf` eats up the backslashes. It would be simpler and safer to conscatenate strings with `['cd ',folder]`.

Comment: Just for the record `sprintf` only manipulates the format string, e.g. `cd %s`, not the input string so `STR` would still have the backslashes. I'm pretty sure the problem with the input to bash (which is a bit surprising since I would have thought the example code would work). The other issue may be that something else in the path is wrong ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to escape the spaces. In general I prefer to wrap all arguments that have spaces with double quotes. I would have guessed that escaping the path would work as well, but maybe not ...

This should work ... and it is much easier to read (IMHO).

```
folder = '"/Users/myuser/Desktop/OneDrive - - Company Name/foldername-AVL"'
STR = sprintf('cd %s',folder);
system(STR)
```

OR - moving " to sprintf

```
folder = '/Users/myuser/Desktop/OneDrive - - Company Name/foldername-AVL'
STR = sprintf('cd "%s"',folder);
system(STR)
```